# How is this sentence translated?

Tags: grammar

I came across a post on X (twitter) today and in this post the person was talking about meeting their fave Sugai Yuuka: 「菅井友香さんのファンミーティング当たった！！！！！忙しいけど生きる意味になった人に会えるの嬉しすぎる」 What does 「生きる意味になった人」mean in this sentence?

Comment: Not 100 percent sure, but this sounds like they're saying that she "came to life" for them.  In other words, she was no longer some personality to see on a screen but became a real person because they saw her in person, in flesh and blood.  That the sense I get, though I can't exactly parse out how I get there.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to 生きがい, he's saying he is happy to meet the person that became the "meaning" of his life.